# Outlook 2013 - Changing IMAP special folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 2013 doesn't allow to set the various IMAP special folders, as it detects automatically the right ones (comments on MS' attitude are not necessary). Unfortunately, in my case it got the wrong "Sent Items" folder and I need a way to change it. I've looked in the registry and the various files but can't find the raw setting.

For one of the accounts, the server is Exchange 2007, and one other uses a server which doesn't support XLIST, so no luck there.

I have already recreated the profile a couple of times and I seriously wish to avoid doing it again, for the tons of other IMAP problems afflicting the several accounts that I need to recreate (and the days needed to re-sync everything).

**Is there a hack to force Outlook to use the correct special folders?**

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there doesn't seem to be such a hack.

The point of XLIST of course is to avoid the need to maintain settings. Unfortunately, IMAP has always suffered from incompatibility issues.

I'm really surprised that you are getting problems with Exchange though, even over IMAP, I've not experienced that with previous versions of Outlook. Unfortunately, I don't have an Exchange server to test with just now.

I did note that the popular Dovecot has XLIST support though only in the v2 stream. I'm still running my server is running the v1 stream so I can't test that either just now.

I assume that you are not in the position to upgrade the servers? Mozilla Thunderbird is the client of choice for me for IMAP accounts. I did toy with Outlook 2013 in the hope that I could get down to a single client but it is too horrible compared to Thunderbird for my personal and consultancy emails. So I keep Outlook purely for customer Exchange email connectivity. Indeed, I use my iPhone and iPad more and more for email and calendar anyway.

Comment: Never had a problem with the previous Outlook versions. It's 2013 that is truly terrible for anything related to IMAP.

Comment: It's the usual Microsoft stuff I'm afraid. IMAP *is* quite tricky to get right but MS have long had a troubled interaction with it. I'm afraid that if you really want IMAP, one of the other mail clients will serve you far better or use something like "[Roundcube](http://www.roundcube.net/)" as a web interface.

Comment: But you agree that the folder settings must be stored somewhere...

Comment: Well, in *theory*, they must of course. But that doesn't mean that you can get to them. They may be encoded in some fashion. I assume that you've done a search of the registry? You'd also need to do a detailed search of the AppData folder for the user profile.